# query postgis raster map with the dynamic request?

Tags: geoserver

Can parametric SQL View be used for postgis raster map in geoserver?
Or how can I query postgis raster map with the dynamic request?

Answer (score 1):

Caution note: I'm not the writer of the module and I have very little experience with it, but I'm a geotools developer and I've worked on the imagemosaic (non jdbc) module.

I believe what you're looking for is currently not possible, and would require changes to the imagemosaic-jdbc store. In particular, it would be useful if the store exposed a CQL filtering parameter like the imagemosaic module does, which could be used to filter tiles involved in the mosaic.
If instead you need to filter on a pixel basis, or actually provide your own query, then much deeper changes would likely need to be performed.

You should probably ask on geotools-devel or geoserver-users to get a definitive answer.

Comment: Thank you Andrea. Is it possible to build filtering on postgis-raster ?

Comment: I believe it might be, if you modify its code to allow for filtering. As said, contact the mailing lists, there you can find the original developer of the plugin.